# How to display testimonials using React-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a dummy testimonials.I want to display it as a slider.
I am using React-Bootstrap but I am not able to get the desired result.

Here is the code.

```
const testimonial: [
            {
              content:
                'Over all though it was a great experience and we have had lots of great feedback. We already started promoting our next event and I have been approached by 4 other companies who want to know more about it as they want to use it for their own events.',
              author: 'Sarah M., Director of Events',
          
            },
            {
              content:
                'I cannot tell you how much we loved using this silent auction software. Everything was seamless…from set up, to bidding, to payment. We will absolutely use MyEvent next year.',
              author: 'Sarah M., CCHS Foundation',
         
            },
            {
              content:
                "I tried MyEvent instead of typical paper raffle tickets. The system was easy to set up online and people who couldn't attend the event were still able to enter the raffle, which was HUGE bump in revenue.",
              author: 'Alexander B., Pan-Mass Challenge',
    
            },
            {
              content:
                'MyEvent is a great way to bring in money for your Fund A Need. The 24/7 tech support allows you to feel confident, and the platform makes your Fund a Need so much easier to run. Well definitely be using MyEvent again.',
              author: 'Amy C., One Less Orphan Fund',
       
            },
          ]
   testimonial.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                { item.content && (
                  <div className="aceele-infos" key={index}>
                     <Carousel>
                       <Carousel.Item>
                          <Carousel.Caption>
                            <span className="signup-infos">{`"${item.content}"`}</span>
                            <div className="awnor-infos">
                                <span className="signup-infos">
                                     {`-`}
                                     {item.author}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                    </Carousel.Item>
                  </Carousel>     
                 </div>
```

But I am not getting the result how I want.
Here is an image how I want.
[image]

Comment: you should map over the carousel,Items rather than the carousel component itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map over your Carousel Items and not the entire div because you only want the carousel items to repeat inside the carousel and not the entire carousel.

Your return statement would look something like this:

```
<div>
      <Carousel interval={1000}>
        {testimonial.map((c, index) => {
          return (
            <Carousel.Item interval={5000}>
              <div style={{ height: 500, background: "black", color: "white" }}>
                <p>{c.content}</p>
              </div>
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <p>{c.author}</p>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
```

I also have a working example for you in codesandbox below
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-aryabhata-qsb9g?file=/src/App.js:1332-1796